# ffmpeg hangs indefinitely when multiple instances are executed

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I have some 20k+ mp3s that I am trying to extract their thumbnail and save them as jpeg files on disk. I am using ffmpeg to get the job done. In order to speed things up I created a java application that runs five threads and processes five images at the same time.

The problem is that sometimes ffmpeg hangs. I check htop and I see five instances of ffmpeg running with no CPU usage, they just sit there doing nothing.

If I however opt to use a single thread things work fine. This is how I run ffmpeg to extract the audio thumbnail:

```
private void vGetAudioFrames(String input)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i" , input, input + ".jpg");
        Process process = procBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
}
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. The call is too simple and I'm not sure if I need additional parameters to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that, it seems to be that it hangs when the output file already exists. There was a flow in my queue retrieval that caused the same file to be pulled twice on the same cycle.

Comment: Consider adding the `-n` global option (before `-i`).

Comment: -n tells ffmpeg to not overwrite existing files. -y says to do that. Its hanging because when the output file exists it prompts you if you want to overwrite and waits for the user input.